# Nested Route link_to helper working in one place but not another

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a nested routes problem that I can not figure out.  I have an app that has nested routes like so:

```
resources :events do
  resources :sessions
end
```

I am trying to use the following link_to in my code:

```
<%= link_to "New Session", new_event_session_path %>
```

When I run rake routes, it will show the proper URL with a GET method existing:

```
new_event_session GET    /events/:event_id/sessions/new(.:format)      {:action=>"new", :controller=>"sessions"}
```

When I try to use the link_to in one place it works, when I try to use it in another place it does not, it instead will give me this error:

```
No route matches {:controller=>"sessions", :action=>"new"}
```

The only difference between the two files is the location of the files in the app (one is under views/events the other is under views/sessions and the url being called:

/events/1 --vs-- /events/1/sessions

I am still a noob with rails, so this is probably a stupid question, but I have hit a bit of a wall.  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to pass event object to path helper:

```
new_event_session_path(@event)
```