# New Route link_to working in one place but not in another

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I've created a new action in my controller, groups_controller.rb

```
def add_member
 @group = Group.find(params[:id])
 @user = User.find(params[:user])
 @group.add_member(@user)
 redirect_to :back
end
```

And in the group.rb, add_member is defined as:

```
def add_member(user)
 self.working_groups.build(:user_id => user.id, :position => self.users.count, :role => 'member')
 self.save
end
```

I've also created the corresponding route:

```
resources :groups do
 member do
  get 'add_member'
 end
end
```

So when I do rake routes, I get:

```
add_member_group GET    /groups/:id/add_member(.:format) groups#add_member
```

So, It works properly when I use this on my Show template

```
<%= link_to "Join", add_member_group_path(:user =>current_user.id, :group=> invitation.group.id) , :class => 'btn-primary' %>
```

But when trying to use the same link in my index template, I get a routing error:

```
ActionController::RoutingError at /groups
No route matches {:action=>"add_member", :controller=>"groups", :user=>1, :group=>12}
```

Any idea of what am I missing here? I tried the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5850890/nested-route-link-to-helper-working-in-one-place-but-not-another), but that didn't make the trick.

Thanks

Comment: Try with replacing: `<%= link_to "Join", add_member_group_path(current_user, invitation.group) , :class => 'btn-primary' %>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your route needs an `id` parameter and you don't provide one. You only provide an `user` and a `group`.

In the `show` view, you already have an `id` in your params so it is reused.

In your `index` view you do not have any `id` so Rails says it can't find your route, because it misses the `id`.

You should write your link like this:

```
<%= link_to "Join", add_member_group_path(:user =>current_user.id, :id=> invitation.group.id) , :class => 'btn-primary' %>
```

Or like this:

```
<%= link_to "Join", add_member_group_path(invitation.group, :user =>current_user.id) , :class => 'btn-primary' %>
```